# Searching and comparing various values using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to create a macro which will:

1. Get the value from the cell A1 search this value in column C.
2. If the value in cell A1 exists in column C, the macro needs to be compare the value in cell B1 with values in column D.
3. If the value in cell A1 exists in column C AND the value in cell B1 exists in column D, then the text "Values found" should appear in cell E1.

The above needs to happen for all non empty rows in column A.

I was trying to use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$138,0)),"Load number not found","Load number found")
```

But it not working as I want. I have limited access to internet so I can't check all web sites. Would you please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if A1 is in column C **and** if B1 is in column D (*in the same row A1 was found in column C*), then you need to do the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C:$C,0)),"Load number not found",IF(B1=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A1,$C:$C,0),1),"Load number found","Load number not found"))
```

The first IF checks if A1 is in column C, the second IF checks if B1 is in column D (*in the same row A1 was found in column C*)

It will return "Load number found" only if both conditions are true. Otherwise it will return "Load number not found".

You can write a macro to do the same thing. But the easier way is to **lock the cells in column E only and protect the sheet so that users will not accidentally change any of the formulas**.

---

Update:

Since Column C can have duplicates, need to use the following array formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,(A1=$C:$C)*(B1=$D:$D),0)),"Load number not found","Load number found")
```

When you paste this formula to E1, make sure to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Ok so IF is TRUE when both conditions are true which is from logical point of view right. But let me explain. Example: In column A i have names in Column B i have phone numbers. I want to identify if  the value for pair from column A and B match the values for pair from column C and D. I can find Samntha in Column C but it does not mean that Samantha's phone found on column D will reffer to Samantha in column C. In your explanation both conditions will be true because both values will be found somewhere (Samantha from example may be found in row C1460 and her phone in D13)

Comment: Ok it was working for many rows at beginning at the file but later it stops.

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. Was working off your formula. And that only had the columns selected to 138 rows. I have included the entire column now

Comment: It still does not work. I could add example file but i can't.

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in column C. If so it will not work since the formula will check for the first match on column C and then look if on column D that row = B1

Comment: Unfortunately it is possible because according to my example with phone numbers Aliston can have sister Amy and they both can have same Phone number. Is it any way to make it works for not only for firtst match ?

Comment: In that case, you need to use an array formula. Use this `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,(A1=$C:$C)*(B1=$D:$D),0)),"Load number not found","Load number found")` When you paste this formula to E1, make sure to press Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead of just pressing the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, a conventional solution with formulae is to concatenate your C and D column data and then search that. If you insert a new columnC with:

```
=D2&E2
```

copied down to suit you could apply (but say in ColumnF rather than ColumnE) your existing formula with only slight modification:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1&B1,$C$2:$C$138,0)),"Load number not found","Load number found")
```

subject to quite what is in which row.

Comment: Thanks. It is some kind of idea. But i need something which prevent others who are not familiar with Excel to do something wrong. That is why I need macro. We have many files like that with thousand of lines.